# update row check duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I hope you can help me with the correct SQL syntax.

```
main_accounts (table1)
'---id, group_name, account_name, payment_method

payments (table2)
'---id, account_name, payment_method
```

What I am trying to do is to update the `account_name` row in payments where `payment_method` is equal to `payment_method` in `main_accounts` table.

I tried:

```
update payments 
set account_name = (select account_name 
                    from main_accounts 
                    where payment_method = payment_method) 
WHERE payment_method = payment_method
```

but it's saying:

> **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

So I don't know... I wish I could do this:

```
update payments 
set account_name = (select account_name 
                    from main_accounts 
                    where payment_method = **{is equal to payment_method in main_accounts table}**
```

Additionally, I wish I could make this as a trigger that when `main_accounts` table is updated, `account_name` goes automatically to `payments table` where the `account_name` is printed to the column when `payment_method` matches the `payment_method` in `main_accounts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error, cause your subquery is returning more than 1 value which can't be used in `SET` statement. You should do a `JOIN` with other table in question while performing the `UPDATE` statement. Something like

```
UPDATE payments a 
    JOIN main_accounts b ON a.payment_method = b.payment_method        
SET a.account_name = b.account_name;
```

Comment: You are craaaaazyy!! That was unbelievable.. It worked Sir! Thank you so much! I hope you help more people like me.. Thank you so so much!

oh.. 1 question, I can simple insert this in a trigger after update right?

Comment: @MarkJuni, if you mean placing the same UPDATE statement in a trigger then yes you can. Consider, accepting the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you once again.. I am sorry if I am disturbing you Sir, I have 1 last question, if I delete the account_name in the main accounts, what trigger syntax should I do to delete that certain entry "account_name" from payments?

Thank you so much, you have saved me a lot of time...
You made my day. :D :D

Comment: @MarkJuni, that's alright but for shake of clarity it's not recommended to ask multiple question in a single post. Your question per your latest comment is separate than current question. Will suggest you to post a separate question and either myself or somebody else will surely able to help. You may link this post in your newly opened post if needed.